# Optimize a SQL Server  query

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a SQL Server query :

```
(
    SELECT k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id AS id
    FROM   k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles
            INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master  ON  k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id
    WHERE   (
                k12_dms_institution_master.state_id='63'
                AND k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id='1'
            )
    GROUP BY
             k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
) 
INTERSECT 
(
    SELECT k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id AS id
    FROM   k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles
            INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master  ON  k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id
    WHERE   (
                k12_dms_institution_master.state_id='63'
                AND k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id='2'
            )
    GROUP BY
             k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
) 
INTERSECT 
(
    SELECT k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id AS id
    FROM   k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles
            INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master  ON  k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id
    WHERE   (
                k12_dms_institution_master.state_id='63'
                AND k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id='3'
            )
    GROUP BY
             k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
) 
INTERSECT 
(
    SELECT k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id AS id
    FROM   k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles
            INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master  ON  k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id
    WHERE   (
                k12_dms_institution_master.state_id='63'
                AND k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id='4'
            )
    GROUP BY
             k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
)
```

Is there any way to optimize the above query.Intersection is required only on the basis of 
Where clause.I want to fetch all the job titles which are common to all grade levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the query more concise as follows:

```
SELECT IJT.job_title_id AS id
FROM k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles AS IJT
INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master AS IM
ON IM.id = IJT.inst_id
WHERE IM.state_id='63'
AND IJT.glevel_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')
GROUP BY IJT.job_title_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IJT.glevel_id) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for. (untested)

```
 SELECT k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id AS id
    FROM   k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles
            INNER JOIN k12_dms_institution_master  ON  k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id
    WHERE   (
                k12_dms_institution_master.state_id='63'
                AND (select count( disctinct k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id) from k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles where k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id in ('1','2','3','4')) = 4
            )
    GROUP BY
             k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
```

Comment: No I Just want to fetch the job titles which are common to all grade levels.